# insert values into integer array from List of type string

Tags: java, arrays, list, file-handling

I want the values printed in line 5 to be inserted into an integer array.
The file contains both **integer values and String values**.
****I am still in learning process****
Sorry i changed the question a bit.
Thank you

```
     File f = new File("SampleInput.txt");
          try{
               ArrayList<String> lines = get_arraylist_from_file(f);       
               for(int x =23; x < lines.size(); x++){
                   System.out.println(lines.get(x));
                   **enter code here**
               }
            }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("File not found!!!!");
    }
}
public static ArrayList<String> get_arraylist_from_file(File f) 
    throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    s = new Scanner(f);
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        list.add(s.next());
    }
    s.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a List instead of an Array?

Answer (score 1):

```
      List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>();
      File f = new File("SampleInput.txt");
      try{
           ArrayList<String> lines = get_arraylist_from_file(f);       
           for(int x =23; x < lines.size(); x++){
               System.out.println(lines.get(x));
               **enter code here**
               numList.add(Integer.parseInt(lines.get(x))); 
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier to use an ArrayList of Integers as follows

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
File f = new File("SampleInput.txt");
          try{
               ArrayList<String> lines = get_arraylist_from_file(f);       
               for(int x =23; x < lines.size(); x++){
                   System.out.println(lines.get(x));
                   list.add(Integer.parseInt(lines.get(x)));
               }
            }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("File not found!!!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like this,

```
try{
  ArrayList<String> lines = get_arraylist_from_file(f);
  ArrayList<int> intLines = new ArrayList();
  for (int x = 23; x < lines.size(); x++) {
    System.out.println(lines.get(x));
    intLines.add(Integer.parseInt(lines.get(x)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an int array outside of the loop of the appropriate size, and then just parse the strings and add them to the array in the loop:

```
           ArrayList<String> lines = get_arraylist_from_file(f); 
           int[] intArray = new int[lines.size-23];
           for(int x =23; x < lines.size(); x++){
               System.out.println(lines.get(x));
               //**enter code here**
               String line = lines.get(x);
               intArray[x-23] = Integer.parseInt(line);
           }
```

Comment: You could also just do `= Integer.parseInt(lines.get(x));`